Git update-git-for-windows command gives curl error 43
when i run git update-git-for-windows command on my command prompt gives following error even i tried running command prompt as administrator gave same error output
git update-git-for-windows
Git for Windows 2.45.2.windows.1 (64-bit)
Update 2.47.0.windows.2 is available
curl: (43) A libcurl function was given a bad argument


This is an issue with curl in this specific Git release. You have to update to a newer version manually.
https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/13845#issuecomment-2453436283

Ensure that you are using a recent version of Git. Older versions of Git for Windows might have compatibility issues with curl. If you’re using an older version, consider updating Git manually by downloading the latest installer from the official site.
If above solution is not working, uninstall Git for Windows from your system, restart, and then download and install the latest version.

Try running the command from git bash, not CMD.
